# Extract a certain part of a string

Tags: php, string

I have an array which contains the following as one of it's values

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="Mon Mar 04 08:52:45 PST 2013"/>
```

How do i extract the March 4th 2013 out of there? This is a dynamic field and will always be changing.  I can't seem to find the right way to do it

I want to be able to just echo $datepub; and just have the date.

Thanks

Comment: xml? use dom+xpath: `//meta/@content`

Comment: You can use regular expressions to extract the content in between content="Mon Mar 04 08:52:45 PST 2013"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way could be exploding it:

```
//dividing the string by whitespaces
$parts = explode(' ', $datepub);  

echo $parts[1]; //month (Mar)
echo $parts[2]; //day (04)
echo $parts[5]; //year (2013)
```

Then you could make use of [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function to convert it to any other desirable format:

```
//creating a valid date format
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', $parts[1].'/'.$parts[2].'/'.$parts[5]);

//formating the date as we want
$finalDate = $newDate->format('F jS Y'); //March 4th 2013
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe that I did not think of explode.  I ended up having to tweak it a bit to the following  $idate =   explode(' ', $i['date']);
$newDate = ($idate[3].' '.$idate[4].' '.str_replace("\"/>", "", $idate[7])); But worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b)'s answer with a code example using [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

```
$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?><meta itemprop="datePublished" content="Mon Mar 04 08:52:45 PST 2013"/>'; // your XML
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

// select all <meta> nodes in the document that have the "content" attribute
$xpath1 = $xml->xpath('//meta[@content]');
foreach ($xpath1 as $key => $node) {
    echo $node->attributes()->content; // Mon Mar 04 08:52:45 PST 2013
}

// Marc B's select "content" attribute for all <meta> nodes in the document
$xpath2 = $xml->xpath('//meta/@content');
foreach ($xpath2 as $key => $node) {
    echo $node->content; // Mon Mar 04 08:52:45 PST 2013
}
```